# Filter rows based on certain conditions in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data consists of three column:- reward date(R_date), reward name(R_Name) and employee name(E_Name), what I want is to get those employees who won **same** award three or more than three times in a particular year. In pandas I want to write the code. please help if anyone knows.

**For eg**

*My data*

| E_Name | R_Name | R_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | R10 | 2019-02-02 |
| A | R10 | 2020-02-02 |
| A | R5 | 2020-02-02 |
| A | R10 | 2020-04-02 |
| A | R10 | 2020-12-12 |
| B | R5 | 2020-07-03 |
| B | R5 | 2020-10-11 |
| C | R10 | 2020-03-01 |
| C | R5 | 2020-05-02 |
| D | R5 | 2019-02-02 |
| D | R2 | 2019-03-02 |
| D | R5 | 2019-02-05 |
| D | R5 | 2019-06-02 |
| D | R5 | 2020-03-04 |

*Output*

| E_Name | R_Name | Year | Reward_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | R10 | 2020 | 3 |
| D | R5 | 2019 | 3 |

This is my first post..pls let me know if I have done any mistakes in explaining the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get what you want with the below code, broken down in steps:

Get the year in a new column using `dt.year`:

```
df['year'] = df['R_date'].dt.year
```

Create a column with the 'Reward_Count', using the amalgamation of `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df['Reward Count'] = df.groupby(['E_Name','year','R_Name'])['R_Name'].transform('count')
```

Get your desired output by keeping people with >= 3 rewards, and drop duplicates using `drop_duplicates()`:

```
output = (df[df['Reward Count'] >= 3]).drop_duplicates('E_Name')

print(output)

  E_Name R_Name     R_date  year  Reward Count
1      A    R10 2020-02-02  2020             3
9      D     R5 2019-02-02  2019             3
```

Comment: @sophode for me you are a genius man, hatsoff bro. God bless you. Another thing is if I want to ask a qstn again then it won't allow me to do that it will show _u can post after 90 min_ actually I'm new to stack overflow that's why I thought to ask you. How can I reach out to u in case I need help again from you.

Comment: Do you have another question already? If it's a simple one you can ask it here and I can post another answer below perhaps?

Comment: no brother, I don't have an immediate qstn right now but the thing is I want to reach out to you whenever I need any help in future because if for next qstn I don't get any instant replies like what you have just replied instantly that's why I'm worried. I just want to improve my coding skills from you. Is it possible?

Comment: Well mate I am not all day in stackoverflow :) so unfortunately the best way will be through here, as I can also get reputation any time I help you. It's a give and take game. Try giving an upvote, and I'll give you one too to get you started.

Comment: I tried to vote but it says **Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score**. When I posted this qstn how did u get to know about that post, did u received any notification in your system or you searched a keyword something that get matched with my title?